# aligning the image and text vertically in the list item

Tags: css, styles, html-lists

Using the css style below will display a list of anchor tag horizontally.

But, I cannot seem to get the image and text to display veritcally in each list item.  Any suggestion on how to do that.

Thank you

My solution to the problem

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
li
{
display:inline;
}

table
{
display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul> 
<li>
<table>
<tr><a href="#"><img /></a></tr>
<tr><a href="#">one</a></tr>
</table>
</li> 
<li>
<table>
<tr><a href="#"><img /></a></tr>
<tr><a href="#">two</a></tr>
</table>
</li> 
<li>
<table>
<tr><a href="#"><img /></a></tr>
<tr><a href="#">three</a></tr>
</table>
</li> 
<li>
<table>
<tr><a href="#"><img /></a></tr>
<tr><a href="#">four</a></tr>
</table>
</li> 
<li>
<table>
<tr><a href="#"><img /></a></tr>
<tr><a href="#">five</a></tr>
</table>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `<br />` before the text, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img /><br />one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img /><br />two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img /><br />three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img /><br />four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img /><br />five</a></li>
</ul>
```

And change the CSS to this:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using the div tag cause the list to display vertically instead of horizontally

Comment: I changed my answer after re-reading your question. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: the inline-block cause the list to display vertically

Comment: The `inline-block` should cause the list to be horizontal. I don't think I understand your question. Can you post an image of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @user1415038 Unfortunately, I'm new to this forum so I have no posted enough to be allowed to post a image

Comment: Ok. To be clear, you said you want "... image and text to display veritcally in each list item", but you want "... a list of anchor tag[s] horizontally" so you want a horizontal list of links, each having an image on top and vertically-aligned text on the bottom. Do I have that right? It's hard to explain with just text.

Comment: Yes, you described it perfectly. I was able to find a answer which I posted above

Answer (score 0):

Are the images all the same height? If so, you could apply a `line-height` value to a `li a` rule. You might have to fiddle with it to find the right value, but that would work.

Comment: yes the images are of a fixed height and width.  Let me try that out